# How to connect to SAP HANA using ruby Sequel

Tags: ruby, sequel

Hi any ideas on how to connect to sap hana db using sequel gem?
Can I use odbc? I used sequel for my mysql, postgres connections. I wonder if I can use it for sap hana

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using Rails you could use https://github.com/SAP/activerecord-hana-adapter together with the ODBC driver for HANA.

Alternatively if you're using jRuby you could use the Java SDK https://prograils.com/posts/getting-your-rails-app-running-on-the-sap-hana-cloud-platform.